# Magento2.3.1 getting issue when update qty

Tags: magento2, addtocart, shopping-cart, mini-cart, qty-increment

How to solve below error when trying to update qty in cart?

"Something went wrong while saving the page. Please refresh the page and try again."

Comment: Check the logs please.

Comment: Not have any logs for this.

Comment: Is this the minicart or the actual cart page? In case of the second; does your cart form have a formkey? <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>

Comment: yes, I was already trying with formkey but still issue i'm facing.

Comment: Check updateItemQty controller response please. Which value return?